# copy project / folder flutter to another computer

Tags: dart, flutter

I copied a project that I am developing in the notebook to my desktop computer, but the path where the flutter sdk is installed in the folder is different, and this caused several errors in the project, since the compiler does not find the sdk ..
which files I need to change to correctly reference the new sdk path on the desktop.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the files and folders listed in `.gitignore`, `android/.gitignore` and `ios/.gitignore`. They are regenerated automatically.

If you use Git (GitHub) to commit and clone, these files and folders will be omitted automatically because of `.gitignore` files.

**Update**

The 3 `.gitignore` files were unified into a single one.

Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26014

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

1. Deleted `.gitignore` files
2. Run `flutter clean project`

Then it worked!

Comment: think I ran flutter pub get after flutter clean, then it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Delete .gitignore files:-
There will be 3 .gitignore files

1. In main directory
2. In android directory
3. In IOS directory

I tried this procedure to run my flutter project which i built in fedora (linux) 
and copied and run in mac